how to list the available collections within some document path ? firestore
Is there way to get list of all the collection (ids) within some given document path ?
after doing some searches i come to know about listCollectionIds but it is not available for client side use (please correct me if there is any)
maintaining a record of the collections could be the one way but it will be better if someone can suggest a better way / str.

There is no API to list collections in the client-side SDKs. You can either maintain your own list/markers in documents, or you can wrap the Admin SDK (which does have such funcionality iirc) in an endpoint that your client calls.

Have a look at this article: How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?

thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your suggestions and i am still figuring what will be the best  for my case.

@RenaudTarnec i did not but the blog looks nice i will definitely  go though it.  thanks
